# Why is LINQ not letting me OrderBy one of my data points?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

I have this code:

```
return inventoryItems
    .Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.ID, ID))
    .Take(CountToFetch);
```

...but I want to order the results, like so:

```
return inventoryItems
    .Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.ID, ID))
    .Take(CountToFetch)
    .OrderBy(i.pksize);
```

...however, the final `i` is red/out of scope. Why? Trying to position the `OrderBy()` prior to the `Take()` makes no difference.

Comment: What's stopping you from redefining it? `return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.ID, ID)).Take(CountToFetch).OrderBy(i => i.pksize);`

Comment: `OrderBy(i=>i.pksize);` ?? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Comment: Haha, I suspect that perhaps you had been up very late at this point and probably should go to sleep :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.ID, ID))
                     .Take(CountToFetch)
                     .OrderBy(i => i.pksize);
```

And maybe you should change `OrderBy` and `Take` order to make results predictable:

```
return inventoryItems.Where(i => 0 < String.Compare(i.ID, ID))
                     .OrderBy(i => i.pksize)
                     .Take(CountToFetch);
```

Comment: Good point on `Take`. It could be the first is what is really wanted, but your second is much more common.

Answer (score 3):

There's no `i` in the `OrderBy`.

You want `OrderBy(i => i.pksize)` (or indeed `x => x.pksize`, `whatever => whatever.pksize`, etc.)

The sort of syntax that allows `from x in something where x.IsOkay orderby x.Priority` etc. uses the same variable label all the way through, but it gets turned into more than one lambda expression, which are each separate from each other. (`something.Where(x => x.IsOkay).OrderBy(x => x.Priority)`, but they need to each be full expressions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've tried to use the `i` you declared in `Where`. If you look closely at the brackets, you should see that it is actually no longer in scope within the `OrderBy`. So the  first problem is you're trying to use an out-of-scope variable.

`OrderBy` actually needs to be able to check the property on each element in the `IEnumerable`, so it doesn't make sense to only pass it the value of *one* element's property. It needs to know *how* to get the property for each element, which is why you typically pass in a lambda expression, anonymous delegate or method.

As the others pointed out, you can solve the problem by using an lambda expression like you did in `Where`:

```
.OrderBy(i => i.pksize)
```

Comment: Yes, I already did that; that's why I marked Marcin's answer as correctomundo.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon That answer didn't address your question: "Why?".